# Workflow Foundation - Pending Timers on Server Restart

Tags: workflow-foundation-4, delayed-execution, long-running-processes

I have a workflow built in a way that it has delay activity which causes it to persist, and after delay has expired, a notification is sent. Workflow is exposed via Workflow Services.

This works perfect except for the scenarios when the server restart occurs or server is brought down for a maintenance for a day or two and timers were already expired. In that case, notification is not sent until the first request related to particular workflow arrives to WCF endpoints.

I have to mention that application pool is already set to alwaysRunning.

Is there anything else that has to be added for IIS/AppFabric to check pending timers that should have already been executed?

I'm using Workflow Foundation 4.5.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Issue has been caused by AppFabric not being set properly.

Comment: I am has a similar issue but am not using AppFabric.  Can you share some of the settings in AppFabric that caused your issue?  It would help me in troubleshooting my situation.